# Don't want to clear out the database after Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have done a dump into myapp_test of a lot of data that I want to run my tests against. It seems that the database is being dropped before the tests run because. After I run `rspec` the database that I just poplulated is empty.

I do a `mysql -u root -p myapp < myapp_db.sql` to set up the db.

I know I should use FactoryGirl to setup the db ... but it is so huge. I would rather just dump into a test db and test against it.

Any ideas on how to keep the db... maybe just rollback the interactions run with rspec?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that you're just doing it wrong.

If you were to setup a test database before the entire test suite and then run a bunch of specs which may change the state of the database you are going to run into test orderings issues, flapping tests etc - big time.